# Create batches out of time-series streaming data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, data-science

I have streaming data with lines like

```
[timestamp; ID; Value1; Value2]
```

that should arrive in spark (ip:port) in correct order and that can be partitioned by ID.

Now I am trying to batch/group the streaming data depending on a condition - i.e. "create new RDD and put in all lines in the stream (with the same ID and sorted by timestamp) until Value1=0".

As a result - I need several RDDs/DataFrames/... containing a sequence identified by a CONDITION e.g. {Value1=0}:

```
[2017010100001; ID; 0; 0]
[2017010100001; ID; 10; 5]
[2017010100001; ID; 11; 9]
[2017010100001; ID; 8; 4]
[2017010100001; ID; 0; 1]
```

How can this be achieved?

Any help or hints are very much appreciated!

Comment: so what is the question exactly?

Comment: Hi Chitral - the question is how this can be done with Spark - or more specific: which spark function or logic could help in this endeavor.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from what I understand you need to do this for your data source,

- Setup a queue system like kafka and write a custom partitioner that feeds on the data from your data source and uses ID as partitioning key. This must happen of producer end.
- Next, you need to setup a spark streaming consumer which connects to this kafka queue and reads the messages in micro batches.
- Each micro batch consists of 0 or more RDDs, for each RDD by key sort by timestamp and in the same loop apply your 0/1 logic.

let me know if this helped. Cheers.

Comment: hi chitral, 
how would a kafka queue help? doesnt spar create rdds by partitioning?
as far as i can see - the difficulty lies in the implementation of the 0/1 logic which should create new rdds.

Comment: queue system can act as one of the data sources that allow you to manipulate streaming data with spark. once you get that as RDDs apply what ever logic you have to it